# How to find hidden input value with id and name - Python, bs4

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

Good morning dear SO community. I had a small problem lately when trying to parse HTML. I always use the bs4 module and this was always fine until now. I mostly needed hidden inputs when scraping and could easily find the value  if I searched them by name. But now I found a page where the input has also an id, like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="985207" name="order[ship_address_attributes] 
[id]" id="order_ship_address_attributes_id">
```

i want to find the value, if the rest is known.

I tried it by just leaving the id part away and searching it with the name only, like I am used to, but this didn't go well and I didn't find the value.

my code:

```
soup=bs(r.text, 'lxml')
vle=soup.find('input',{'name':'ship_address_attributes'})['value']
```

I hope to find a way to get the value, in a similar way to how I tried. Is there a method to add just the id like the name? I would be very happy on any help. Thanks a lot and wish the whole community happy holidays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why not select it by `id` ?

```
vle = soup.find('input',{'id':'order_ship_address_attributes_id'})['value']
```

if the `name` value has no space or newline select it with

```
vle = soup.find('input', {'name':'order[ship_address_attributes][id]'})['value']
```

And this will select `input` with `type=hidden` and has attributes `name` also `id`

```
hiddenInputs = soup.select('input[type=hidden]')
for input in hiddenInputs:
    if input.get('name') and input.get('id'):
        print(input['value'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regex` along with `BeautifulSoup` to find the right tag.

For example:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

a = '''<input type="hidden" value="985207" name="order[ship_address_attributes] 
[id]" id="order_ship_address_attributes_id">'''

# Or:
# soup = bs(a, 'lxml')
soup = bs(a, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find('input', {'name': re.compile(r'order\[\w+\]\s+\[\w+\]')})
print(data['value'])  # 985207
```

Or if you want to find the tag with the exact `regex` match, you can do:

```
data = soup.find('input', {'name': re.compile(r'order\[ship_address_attributes\]\s+\[id\]')})
print(data['value'])  # 985207
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I tried to build it in like this:      ´id2 = soup.find('input', {'name': re.compile(r'order\[ship_address_attributes\]\s+\[id\]')})['value']
 print(id2)´   but I get the error     ´soup.find('input', {'name': re.compile(r'order\[ship_address_attributes\]\s+\[id\]')})['value']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable....´

Comment: @PatrickDaRin Note here what i wrote: `re.compile(r'order\[ship_address_attributes\]\s+\[id\]')` we need to escape `[` and `]` inside the regex pattern, if not you'll capture anything and you'll get a `None` as a return.

Comment: @PatrickDaRin Also to capture the return to line `\n` you can use `\s+` it'll capture the spaces inside the regex pattern.